# my nginx server is not starting no matter what I do

Tags: nginx

on 'sudo nginx', the output is:

```
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
    nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()

on 'sudo netstart -tulpan', the output is:

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1417/mongod
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1443/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16662/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1428/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::70                   :::*                    LISTEN      15680/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      15923/node
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      16630/node
tcp6       0      0 :::81                   :::*                    LISTEN      16662/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1428/sshd
```

configuration file is,
'sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default':

```
server {
        listen 81;
        listen [::]:81 ipv6only=on;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
```

I really need help guys: please how do I get the nginx server working?

Comment: Am hosting on digital ocean droplet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nginx is already running that is why.

When you run nginx it goes to background and you wont see anything.

As you can see from your netstat your nginx is already running.

If you want to stop it, use `nginx -s stop`, or for reload use `nginx -s reload`, to run nginx again use `nginx`

Comment: I just confirmed its working, thanks Tarun; I ran, ' systemctl status nginx.service'.